# get xml attribute name using xmldocument

Tags: xml, xmldocument, xml-attribute

I am using C#, framework 3.5. I am reading xml values using xmldocument. I can get the values of attributes but i cannot get the attribute names.
Example: My xml looks like

```
<customer>
 <customerlist name = AAA Age = 23 />
 <customerlist name = BBB Age = 24 />
</customer>
```

I could read values using the following code:

```
foreach(xmlnode node in xmlnodelist)
{
  customerName = node.attributes.getnameditem("name").value;
  customerAge = node.attributes.getnameditem("Age").value;
}
```

How to get attribute name (name,Age) instead of their values. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) has an [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx) collection. The items in this collection are [XmlAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx). XmlAttributes have [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.name.aspx) and [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.value.aspx) properties, among [others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute_properties.aspx).

The following is an example of looping through the attributes for a given node, and outputting the name and value of each attribute.

```
XmlNode node = GetNode();

foreach(XmlAttribute attribute in node.Attributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Name: {0}, Value: {1}.",
        attribute.Name,
        attribute.Value);
}
```

Beware, from the docs for the [XmlNode.Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx):

> If the node is of type XmlNodeType.Element, the attributes of the node
>   are returned. Otherwise, this property returns null.

**Update**

If you know that there are exactly two attributes, and you want both of their names at the same time, you can do something like the following:

```
string attributeOne = node.Attributes[0].Name;
string attributeTwo = node.Attributes[1].Name;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ftsfa87.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So i would like to read the attribute names for the element as a pair like if(1stAttribute.name == "Name" and 2ndAttribute.Name = "Age") then do something. So i need customize the code based on attribute names. So how to get the all the attribute names associated with that element.

Comment: Thanks seth. Yes for now it is going to be 2 attributes but i am not sure what has to be done if i want it more generic.